# Jaspersof iReport-How can I RETURN ALL records when parameter is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have three parameters `$P{Clss}` (select the class from ships), `$P{MinWeight}` and `$P{MaxWeight}`. Whenever I leave the `$P{Clss}` blank it always display no pages.

Whats wrong with my WHERE  clause? I've tried this.

```
where  first.class = $P{Clss} or $P{Clss} is null and displacement between $P{MinWeight} and $P{MaxWeight}


where $P{Clss} is null or $P{Clss} = first.class and displacement between $P{MinWeight} and $P{MaxWeight}
```

I read blogs and questions related to this but somehow it always displays no pages or I guess I'm really just a noob here.

Answer (score 0):

In Jasper report, you need to handle this case in different manner like below,

- Create a new parameter named `ClassParsed` (just naming convention).
- In parameter expression, provide as `$P{Clss} != null && !$P{Clss}.isEmpty() ? " first.class = '"+$P{Clss}+"'" : "true"`
- Then in your query have something like below

`where  $P!{ClassParsed} and displacement between $P{MinWeight} and $P{MaxWeight}`

If you do not give value to parameter $P{Clss} then parameter `ClassParsed` will become like below,

`where  true and displacement between $P{MinWeight} and $P{MaxWeight}`

If you give value to parameter $P{Clss} as say `Class1`, then parameter `ClassParsed` will become like below

`where first.class = 'Class1' and displacement between $P{MinWeight} and $P{MaxWeight}`

Hope this would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

brother, you have to use brackets when defining the jasper parameter i.e;

```
where  first.class = ($P{Clss} or $P{Clss} is null) and displacement between $P{MinWeight} and $P{MaxWeight}
```

Im using these parameters to fetch user location,

```
select * from location where
a.state = $P{state} and
 (a.district = $P{district} or $P{district} is null)
```

if any of the district parameter is null then also report get generated.

**PS : Cheers !!**

Comment: Oops I forget to tell the main the culprit :D,  **see updated answer** .. (Y)